How adjust the build of my angular project after install bootstrap-icons?
I have installed bootstrap-icons in my angular app, but now when I build my project, it creates 2 .woff files in the root folder. And in the main file, they are referenced like this:
src:url(bootstrap-icons.bfa90bda92a84a6a.woff2?dd67030699838ea613ee6dbda90effa6) format("woff2"),url(bootstrap-icons.70a9dee9e5ab72aa.woff?dd67030699838ea613ee6dbda90effa6) format("woff")
Is there a way to create these files in another folder automatically when I build it (and the main file also reference the url like (/assets/bootstrap-icons... )?
